# How to fix d3 parsing error when using function and return value to set "d"?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, svg, d3.js, method-chaining

For brevity, I'm skipping other superfluous chained methods. Note that the first function in this chain works. The second function, does not. And if we make it not a function, d3 is happy assigning `arc` to `d`. Am I missing something about the "d" property, or is this possibly a d3 bug? Maybe "d" expects a different way to bind?

```
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(outerRadius);



    var slice = arcs.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("fill", function(d, i ) {
                        // this function works fine!!!!
                        if(someCondition)
                        {                                
                            return "#3AB3F1";
                        } else if( someOtherCondition)
                        {                               
                            var brightenedColor = colorSpread(sliceArray.length, true)[i];
                            return brightenedColor;
                        } 
                    })                        
                    .attr("d", function(d, i){
                           // this throws an error in d3!!!!!
                           return arc; 
                    })
                    .style('stroke', 'white').....
```

However, if I do not use a function, it works!

```
...
.attr("d", arc )
...
```

The Error code:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="function n(){var n=t.apply(this,arguments),u=e.apply(this,arguments),a=r.apply(this,arguments)+nc,o=i.apply(this,arguments)+nc,c=(a>o&&(c=a,a=o,o=c),o-a),l=Da>c?"0":"1",f=Math.cos(a),s=Math.sin(a),h=Math.cos(o),g=Math.sin(o);return c>=tc?n?"M0,"+u+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 1,1 0,"+-u+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 1,1 0,"+u+"M0,"+n+"A"+n+","+n+" 0 1,0 0,"+-n+"A"+n+","+n+" 0 1,0 0,"+n+"Z":"M0,"+u+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 1,1 0,"+-u+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 1,1 0,"+u+"Z":n?"M"+u*f+","+u*s+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 "+l+",1 "+u*h+","+u*g+"L"+n*h+","+n*g+"A"+n+","+n+" 0 "+l+",0 "+n*f+","+n*s+"Z":"M"+u*f+","+u*s+"A"+u+","+u+" 0 "+l+",1 "+u*h+","+u*g+"L0,0"+"Z"}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object `arc` created by `d3.svg.arc()` is a function itself, which takes the data object attached to the pieSlice as a parameter and returns the path directions string.

So writing this:

```
.attr("d", function(d, i){
       return arc; 
})
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
.attr("d", function(d, i){
       return function(d2, i2){
              /* Do stuff here */
       }; 
})
```

Now there are times in d3 code where you do want one function to return another function -- but this isn't one of those times!  D3 is expecting your function to return a string for the attribute value, and so the arc function gets converted to a string, and that gets set as the attribute value.  And of course your browser doesn't know how to draw a path from directions like "function n(){var n=t.apply...." etc., so it throws an error.

In contrast, when you write

```
.attr("d", arc )
```

d3 checks the value you gave it (`arc`), sees that it is a function, and calls it for each element with the appropriate data and index, and the arc function returns the appropriate path directions string.

If you did need to use your own function, you would then need to *call* the arc function with the data value and index as arguments.  This might happen if the pie data was stored in a sub-property of your data object instead of being the data object as a whole.

```
.attr("d", function(d,i) {

      /* calculate something here */

      return arc(d.pieData); //return the *result* of the arc function
                             // NOT the function itself!

 })
```

I honestly can't thing of any case where you'd have to do it this way for pie data (because you can just change the accessor functions on the arc object instead), but you often see this structure for line graphs, where you have to grab the sub-array of datapoints to pass to the line-drawing function.

Comment: It was to have different arc shapes for different slices depending on the data.

Comment: In what way does `.attr("d", arc )` not work?  You may need to set more options on the arc function if you're not using the default property names, but otherwise that will draw the pie slice for each path based on the data attached to the path.

Comment: Ah, so just set property `outerRadius` on my data objects, and `.attr("d", arc) would apply the data's radius? Might also want to animate between interpolations of start and end angle, for instance, but that function would be called from the transition itself....

Comment: Exactly.  Or if you already have a data property with a different name, you can specify the function for the arc generator to use to access the correct value and optionally scale it, e.g. `arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius( function(d){return scale( d.radiusData ); });`  For animating transitions, see [this series of demos by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346395).